# create .pdf files automatically centura

Tags: plsql, guptateamdeveloper, centura

i'm working in Centura 2.1 team developer and I want to generate (.pdf) files direct from the system and every .pdf file has a unique name according to the data inside this file.

how can I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to look at the page:
https://samples.tdcommunity.net/index.php?dir=

Here is a lot examples working with PDF.

Comment: I will try that

Answer (score 1):

After TeamDeveloper v5 you can use SalReportPrintToFile() which creates a PDF.

Otherwise you could install [PDF995](http://www.pdf995.com/) ( free ) and call some of its many functions if you don't want to use Acrobat Writer ActiveX.

Comment: Unfortunately SalReportPrintToFile()  in version  2.1 allows only rtf or csv ,, I tried to use pdfFactory and it creates pdf files automatically  but the file name is the same name of the QRP file , Is there any way to change the qrp name while printing ?

Comment: Either Copy or Rename the .qrp to what ever name you want before you print it. VisFileRename (sOldFileName, sNewFileName)  or  VisFileCopy (sSourceFile, sTargetFile)